# Converting R cumsum with reset to Python

Tags: python, r, cumsum

I'm trying to convert this R code to Python.

```
mutate(Mod_1minutos = (cumsum(coalesce(Minutos_Desde_Ult_Medida, 0)) + Minutos_Desde_Ult_Medida*0)%/%6) %>%
```

This code creates a new column in the dataframe, and when this sum it's a multiple of 6 it will reset the counter.

How can I do this in Python?

For the coalesce I'm doing this:

```
df_6_minutos['Minutos_Desde_Ult_Medida'] = df_6_minutos['Minutos_Desde_Ult_Medida'].fillna(0)
```

But I don't know what can I do to create a cumsum resetting whenever Mod 6 is equal to 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the full code for this wrangling:

```
df_6_minutos = df %>%

  group_by(Identificador_Locomotiva) %>%
  arrange(Data_Hora_Local_Leitura) %>%

  mutate(Data_Hora_UTC = as.POSIXct(Data_Hora_UTC, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz='')) %>%
  mutate(DT_HR_LOC_PEGADA = as.POSIXct(DT_HR_LOC_PEGADA, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz='')) %>%
  mutate(DT_HR_LOC_DEIXADA = as.POSIXct(DT_HR_LOC_DEIXADA, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz='')) %>%
  mutate(Condicao_Carga_Vagao = ifelse(QTDE_VAG_CAR==0 & QTDE_VAG_VAZ>0,"Vazio",
                                       ifelse(QTDE_VAG_CAR>0 & QTDE_VAG_VAZ==0,"Cheio","CheioEVazio"))) %>%
  mutate(Minutos_Desde_Ult_Medida = as.numeric((Data_Hora_Local_Leitura - lag(Data_Hora_Local_Leitura,1))/60)) %>%
  mutate(Mod_1minutos = (cumsum(coalesce(Minutos_Desde_Ult_Medida, 0)) + Minutos_Desde_Ult_Medida*0)%/%6) %>%
  mutate(Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1 = as.numeric(unlist(sapply(rle(Mod_1minutos)[['lengths']],seq)))) %>%
  mutate(Velocidade_Media_Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo = ave(Medida_Velocidade/10, cumsum(Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1==1), FUN = cummean)) %>%
  mutate(Velocidade_Minima_Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo = ave(Medida_Velocidade/10, cumsum(Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1==1), FUN = cummin)) %>%
  mutate(Velocidade_Maxima_Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo = ave(Medida_Velocidade/10, cumsum(Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1==1), FUN = cummax)) %>%
  mutate(Metros_Minimo_Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo = ave((Medida_Hodometro - lag(Medida_Hodometro,1))*100, cumsum(Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1==1), FUN = cummin)) %>%
  mutate(Max_Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1 = ifelse(lead(Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1,1) < Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1 | Minutos_Desde_Ult_Medida==360,Medidas_Consec_No_Intervalo_1,NA))

df_6_minutos = data.frame(df_6_minutos)
```

I've started converting it to Python doing the following:

```
from dfply import *

df_6_minutos >> group_by('Identificador_Locomotiva')
df_6_minutos >> arrange('Data_Hora_Local_Leitura')

df_6_minutos["Data_Hora_UTC"] = pd.to_datetime(df_6_minutos["Data_Hora_UTC"], format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").dt.tz_localize(None)
df_6_minutos["DT_HR_LOC_PEGADA"] = pd.to_datetime(df_6_minutos["DT_HR_LOC_PEGADA"], format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").dt.tz_localize(None)
df_6_minutos["DT_HR_LOC_DEIXADA"] = pd.to_datetime(df_6_minutos["DT_HR_LOC_DEIXADA"], format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").dt.tz_localize(None)
df_6_minutos["Data_Hora_Local_Leitura"] = pd.to_datetime(df_6_minutos["Data_Hora_Local_Leitura"], format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").dt.tz_localize(None)

vazio_cheio_conditions = [
    (df_6_minutos['QTDE_VAG_CAR'] == 0) & (df_6_minutos['QTDE_VAG_VAZ'] > 0),
    (df_6_minutos['QTDE_VAG_CAR'] > 0) & (df_6_minutos['QTDE_VAG_VAZ'] == 0)]
vazio_cheio_choices = ['Vazio', 'Cheio']

df_6_minutos["Condicao_Carga_Vagao"] = np.select(vazio_cheio_conditions, vazio_cheio_choices, default='CheioEVazio')
```

Comment: Can you please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: The R code is incomplete (you have a trailing pipe (`%>%`) symbol there that leads nowhere). Please show the full code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you should try:

```
df['<column_name>'].cumsum() % 6
```

`%` is the module operator in Python, so you'll get the "cumulative sum above the last multiple of 6.

Otherwise you can try to create a column you want to use to split your data, then do

```py
df.groupby('<column_with_criteria>')['<column_name>'].cumsum()
```

so that you take a cumulative sum within each group. They will be automatically stacked.